# JavaScript Require From Variable

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, require

I'm using the following:

```
props: {
    backgroundImagePath: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: '@/static/images/9.jpeg'
    }
}

:style="{
    backgroundImage: `url(${require(backgroundImagePath)})`
}"
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Cannot find module '@/static/images/9.jpeg'

```
:style="{
    backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/static/images/9.jpeg')})`
}"
```

Works as normal however - I'm not sure why?

For context I'm using NuxtJS.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I noticed you don't have the backticks `` around the url, in the first case.

Comment: This was a formatting error when posting - I've edited the thread - thanks.

Comment: Where is `backgroundImagePath` defined in the first example?

Comment: I have edited the post to update the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 props: {
    backgroundImagePath: {
        required: true,
        default: require('@/static/images/9.jpeg')
    }
 }

 :style="{
     backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImagePath})`
 }"
```

Changing the `backgroundImagePath` prop default value seemed to resolve this.